# Android: using OkHttp with PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, okhttp

I'm building a user registration module in Android. Here's the RegistrationManager.java file that deals with user registration in the database by sending a POST request to the server.

```
import com.marshall.opensurvey.sqlite.user.User;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Call;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Callback;
import com.squareup.okhttp.FormEncodingBuilder;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;

import java.io.IOException;

// user controller class specified in registration activities.
public class RegistrationManager {

    private OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    private final String SERVER_URL = ServerURL.URL_REGISTER;

    public static boolean error;

    // register a new user into mysql database
    public void registerUserIntoMySQL(final User newUser) {
        RequestBody body = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                .add("tag", "register")
                .add("email", newUser.getEmail())
                .add("name", newUser.getName())
                .add("password", newUser.getPassword())
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(SERVER_URL).post(body).build();

        Call call = client.newCall(request);

        call.enqueue(new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

So, as the server receives the tag called "register", the server should register the new user in the database. This is defined in the Register.php file.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
    $tag = $_POST('tag');

    require_once 'mysql/DB_Functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();

    // json response array
    $response = array("error" => FALSE);

    if($tag == 'register') {
        if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

            // receiving the post params
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            // check if user is already existed with the same email
            if ($db->userExists($email)) {

                // user already exists
                $response["error"] = TRUE;
                $response["error_msg"] = "User already exists: " . $email;
                echo json_encode($response);

            } else {
                // create a new user.
                $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password);
                if ($user) {
                    // user stored successfully
                    $response["error"] = FALSE;
                    $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
                    $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
                    $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
                    $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
                    $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
                    echo json_encode($response);
                } else {
                    // user failed to store
                    $response["error"] = TRUE;
                    $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
                    echo json_encode($response);
                }
            }
        } else {
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters (name, email or password) is missing!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }   
    } else {
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Inapproriate tag.";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

} else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required tag is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

So these are the codes I've made so far, but I find the MySQL database is empty. Any solutions please?

Comment: Well are those php varables set? Tell how the code flows. And what is the reply you get?

Comment: You did not implement onFailure() and onResponse(). So how would you be informed?

Comment: Have you set INTERNET permission in AndroidManifest.xml? Any logcat available or not? Try put Log.i(...) inside onResponse and onFailure